# How do I cover Business and Tourism on a single schengen visa but different entries for each

Tags: india, schengen-visas, tourist-visas, multiple-entry, business-travel

I will be travelling to Paris from India on company work for a week - 8 to 12 April. Once I return to India I need to be back in Paris on 22nd April with my family on a holiday, and then from there I go to Switzerland for a week. What sort of a Schengen visa do I need to get to cover both the trips as I will not have time to apply for another visa once I am back from my company trip.

Comment: Note that Switzerland is NOT a Schengen area country. You may need a separate visa for that (the Schengen visa will not cover it but maybe you don't need a visa for Switzerland - probably you do as you imply to have Indian citizenship.

Answer (score 5):

The Schengen system does not have different kinds of visas for business and tourism. It is all done on *uniform short-stay visas*.

If you're planning two trips so close together that you don't have time to apply for a new visa between them, the French consulate *should* entertain an application for a single visa that will cover them both.

Request a 2-entry visa and give details of *both* trips in your application, with full itinerary and so forth. If the electronic application form will not let you trick both "business" and "tourism" in the "purpose of your visit" question, it will probably be least confusing to tick "business" -- it is common to combine business trips with incidental tourism. You will not be rejected for ticking the wrong field here, as long as it is clear from your supporting documentation what it is you propose.